# HTML type="range" value should be generated only after sliding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using html type="Range" to get value between 1-100, i'm not giving any default value but it's taking 50 as the default value. But I want it to take in a value only when I change the slider, until then it shouldn't give out any value. Is there any way for that?

Like in this link, it is taking 25 as the default value.

http://jsfiddle.net/kxbdgwzo/`enter code here`

Comment: Are you asking how to make the label blank until the slider is moved? Or you want it to show zero by default?

Comment: I'm using the slider to change brightness of an image. So if the slider is set to 0, it's applying to the image and making it 0 brightness, if am not specifying any value it's taking in 50 as the default brightness. But I dont want to take it any value by default, it should take value only after I move the slider.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set the initial value as null. Range sliders require an initial value or else they default to the middle value. In this case - for example you can init it at 0 by setting the value property to 0.

```
<html>
<body>

    <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="50" step="1" />

    <h2 id="range">0</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxbdgwzo/4/)

You can hide the value if you want - but you cant completely eliminate it if you want your slider to not auto center the init value.

**Edit:** Another option is to preset your image opacity - and do not pass opacity control to the slider until after the slider is clicked on. Set that slider value to 50 so the image will remain full opaque when the slider is first clicked - but the opacity value will then be controlled by the slider once it gets focus.

Comment: I'm using the slider to change brightness of an image. So if the slider is set to 0, it's applying to the image and making it 0 brightness, if am not specifying any value it's taking in 50 as the default brightness. But I dont want to take it any value by default, it should take value only after I move the slider.

Comment: Yes - I get what you are trying to do - but it unfortunately is not possible to init a range slider with absolutely no value. It needs to know where to place the pip when it is added to the DOM. If you dont give it one - it will just place the pip at the middle value by default.

Your other option is to not use a default range slider and build your own from scratch that does not require an init value for the pip.

Or, set opacity of the image at 1 initially, and dont let the slider apply its values until after it is given focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the initial value to not display, change your javascript thusly:

```
var output = document.getElementById('range');
output.innerHTML = '';

function showValue(newValue) {
    output.innerHTML = newValue;
}

$('#slider').change(function(e) {
    showValue($(this).val());

});
```

Otherwise, if you just want the initial value to be zero, simply add `value="0"` to your `<input>`.

Comment: I'm using the slider to change brightness of an image. So if the slider is set to 0, it's applying to the image and making it 0 brightness, if am not specifying any value it's taking in 50 as the default brightness. But I dont want to take it any value by default, it should take value only after I move the slider.

Comment: As @korgrue's answer states, you can't just null this slider. You'll need to edit your javascript in such a way that it does not apply your slider value until it is changed.